# How to compile C program in Ubuntu if the .c file is in a folder?

Tags: c, ubuntu

I don't know how to compile a C program in Ubuntu if the .c file is in a folder.

When the file is on the desktop I open the terminal, I write `dir`, then `cd Desktop` and then `gcc hello.c -o hello` for example and then `./hello`. How can I do if the program is inside a folder on the desktop?

Comment: `Cd Desktop\DIRECTORY-INSIDE-DESKTOP-WHERE-IS-C-PROGRAM`; `gcc hello.c -o hello`

Answer (score 1):

Do the same as if the .c is in the Desktop but navigate to the folder with `cd folder`

Answer (score 0):

```
cd Desktop
cd folder_name
```

It is pretty simple.